# Testdatageneration with AutoFixture: resolving ICollection<T> without mentioning every single T

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, test-data, autofixture

I try to use [AutoFixture 2](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) to generate testdata for EntityFramework4 classes that have ICollection member.

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Child1> Children1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Child2> Children2 { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual ICollection<Child759> Children759 { get; set; }
    }

    var factory = new Ploeh.AutoFixture.Fixture();
    var parent = factory.CreateAnonymous<Parent>();
```

Since AutoFixture cannot resolve `ICollection<Child1>` i get an `Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException`

The only solution i found so far is to register every possible 'ICollection` like this

```
    var factory = new Fixture();

    factory.Register<ICollection<Child1>>(() =>
        new List<Child1>());
    ...
    factory.Register<ICollection<Child759>>(() =>
        new List<Child759>());

    var parent = factory.CreateAnonymous<Parent>();
```

My question is

**Does anybody know a way or a Convention to tell AutoFixture always to use `List<T>` if a `ICollection<T>` is required?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoFixture 2.1 will have [conventions for various models of multiplicit](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/08/CreatingGeneralPopulatedListsWithAutoFixture.aspx)y. The plan is to get 2.1 out before [GOTO Copenhagen](http://gotocon.com/cph-2011/).